# Keep an object moving along the Y axis appear stationary at a point by moving its X and Z position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need that the camera sees an object in the initial position after moving it on Y axis.
I use some images to explain myself better.
This is the initial position of the object. The main camera will not change position. At the coordinates (0, 0, 0) there is another camera I use for the background image. From this same point I draw Gizmo lines.

[image]

Now through my Editor I move a Plane on the Y axis from 0 to -2. The Y of my object is linked to the Y of the Plane, so it also goes down by 2 units.

[image]

Now comes the part I would like to automate. I want to move the object along the X and Z axis so that its feet appear to the camera as if they are in the same initial position. By manually moving it in Scene View on the X and Z axes, I put the feet in a place that looks like the same point as before and of course it is smaller as it is further away from the camera.

[image]

How can I calculate by code the X and Z coordinates to be assigned to my object's position at a given point on the Y axis, so that one point remains in the same position in screen space?

Comment: Are you asking how to move your scene camera with your object, or are you asking how to lock your player to a specific axis?

Comment: Hi @ Eliasar,
no, the camera is always stopped at the same coordinates. I move the invisible Plane (under the character's feet) on the Y axis and the character follows the Plane. But what I need is that while the character follows the Plane on the Y axis it remains in the same position with respect to the camera. To achieve this I have to update the X and Z axes of the character while it is moved on the Y axis, get the right Vector3 and assign it to the character.

Comment: In short I would need the character always to appear in the center of the yellow circle also moving it on the Y axis.

Comment: Use a Physics.Raycast?

Comment: I'm failing to understand what is the desired effect should be. If you want your camera to keep the player in the same spot, you can child the camera to the player. You can also use a script on the camera to track the player (which will move the camera).

Comment: @Eliasar I edited the post to be more clear.

Comment: I don't think this question deserved a downvote. It was clear, especially after the modifications of @Ruzihm that improved exposition and it does not concern trivial matters. The fact that there was no code does not prove that no effort was made to figure out how to solve the problem but rather that there were no ideas to do this. Just look at my previous posts full of example codes. In my opinion the downvote is a bad practice that should be reserved only for exceptional events, rather better to reward those who offer their time to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rays and planes to calculate this.

Before the object moves, create a `Ray` from the camera to the point on the object you need to keep in the same position:

```
// Where the "feet" are relative to the object's origin
public Vector3 cameraKeepOffset = new Vector3(0f,-1f,0f); 

public Ray perspectiveRay;

...

Vector3 positionToKeep = transform.position + cameraKeepOffset;
Vector3 cameraPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;

perspectiveRay = new Ray(cameraPosition, positionToKeep - cameraPosition);
```

The idea is that whenever the object moves, find where along that ray it can be placed. If we put a horizontal plane at the y position, wherever the ray intersects that plane is where the object should be placed.

So, when the object moves, create a `Plane` where the offset is, find where the `perspectiveRay` intersects it, then move the object so that its offset is at that point:

```
Plane yPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, cameraKeepOffset + transform.position);
float distanceFromCam;
if ( !Raycast(perspectiveRay, out distanceFromCam)) {
    Debug.log("Camera is not pointing at plane");

    // Handle bugs here, return if necessary, etc.
} else {
    Vector3 intersectionPoint = Ray.GetPoint(distanceFromCam);
    transform.position = intersectionPoint - cameraKeepOffset;
}
```